# PHP cURL 403 Forbidden Error (Mackolik.com)

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I tried to get the data from www.mackolik.com with PHP cURL. Actually, I can get the data from almost all page except this page: http://www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/TeamHandler.aspx?command=teamtabs&id=591&seasonName=2015/2016&type=2

This page has statistic of teams. I need this page. How do I get the data of this page? Can you help me?

You can enter this page: http://www.mackolik.com/Takim/591/Amedspor then click "İstatistik" (in english Statistic). I want this part of page. Hopefully, you can understand my problem...

My codes:

```
function poster($url,$fields_string){
    $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'NID=67=pdjIQN5CUKVn0bRgAlqitBk7WHVivLsbLcr7QOWMn35Pq03N1WMy6kxYBPORtaQUPQrfMK4Yo0vVz8tH97ejX3q7P2lNuPjTOhwqaI2bXCgPGSDKkdFoiYIqXubR0cTJ48hIAaKQqiQi_lpoe6edhMglvOO9ynw; PREF=ID=52aa671013493765:U=0cfb5c96530d04e3:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1370266105:LM=1370341612:GM=1:S=Kcc6KUnZwWfy3cOl; OTZ=1800625_34_34__34_; S=talkgadget=38GaRzFbruDPtFjrghEtRw; SID=DQAAALoAAADHyIbtG3J_u2hwNi4N6UQWgXlwOAQL58VRB_0xQYbDiL2HA5zvefboor5YVmHc8Zt5lcA0LCd2Riv4WsW53ZbNCv8Qu_THhIvtRgdEZfgk26LrKmObye1wU62jESQoNdbapFAfEH_IGHSIA0ZKsZrHiWLGVpujKyUvHHGsZc_XZm4Z4tb2bbYWWYAv02mw2njnf4jiKP2QTxnlnKFK77UvWn4FFcahe-XTk8Jlqblu66AlkTGMZpU0BDlYMValdnU; HSID=A6VT_ZJ0ZSm8NTdFf; SSID=A9_PWUXbZLazoEskE; APISID=RSS_BK5QSEmzBxlS/ApSt2fMy1g36vrYvk; SAPISID=ZIMOP9lJ_E8SLdkL/A32W20hPpwgd5Kg1J');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $last = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array($result,$last);
}

$a = poster("http://www.mackolik.com/Takim/591/Amedspor#ui-tabs-1");
$b = poster("http://www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/TeamHandler.aspx?command=teamtabs&id=591&seasonName=2015/2016&type=2");

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy as long as the remote application isn't requiring session cookies or something like that.

On your specific case, the remote server is checking if **Referer** HTTP header exists, if so it should match with internal HOST endpoint (such as clicking over button "*İstatistik*" and firing a ajax req).
Also the request method is **GET**, not POST.
Even though is not strictly required might be a good idea send "X-Requested-With" too, just like the original HTTP request is made.

```
$http_headers = array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0)'
        . 'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0',
    'Accept: */*',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer: http://www.mackolik.com/Takim/591/Amedspor', # IMPORTANT
    'Accept-Language: pt-BR,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
);

$url = 'http://www.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/TeamHandler.aspx';
$url .= '?command=teamtabs&id=591&seasonName=2015/2016&type=2';
$opener = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($opener, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $http_headers,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
));
$content = curl_exec($opener);
curl_close($opener);

echo $content;
```

See HTTP request looks like:

[image]

Comment: @BatuhanKök Hey, I've just add an image from Firefox network inspector.